# Getting error when trying to make table with foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I am making a simple 3 tabled database. However, when I try and make the prod_owners table I keep getting an error. I don't understand why. I tried looking it up on w3school's. Followed its format and I still got it wrong. Could someone explain what I am doing wrong? And how I can possibly fix it.

Error:

```
Static analysis:

3 errors were found during analysis.

A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "FOREIGN KEY" at position 236)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "user_id" at position 249)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "REFERENCES" at position 258)
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE prod_owners ( owner_id int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, user_id int(11) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id), prod_id int(20) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES products (prod_id) )

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id),
    prod_id         int(20)
' at line 8
```

---

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id        int(11)
                    NOT NULL
                    AUTO_INCREMENT
                    PRIMARY KEY,
    phone           int(11)
                    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE products (
    prod_id         int(20)
                    NOT NULL
                    AUTO_INCREMENT
                    PRIMARY KEY,
    info            varchar(1000)
                    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE prod_owners (
    owner_id        int(20)
                    NOT NULL
                    AUTO_INCREMENT
                    PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id         int(11)
                    NOT NULL
                    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id),
    prod_id         int(20)
                    NOT NULL
                    FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES products (prod_id)
);
```

Comment: Try to define foreign key separated by comma as explained [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/) instead of with the column declaration.

Comment: @Ishaan That is what I am doing though?

Comment: So I think you are missing a comma between user_id declaration and Foreign key declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add comma after the column definition.

Look at the below code :

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  user_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  phone INT(11) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE products(
  prod_id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  info VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE prod_owners(
  owner_id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT(11) NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),
  prod_id INT(20) NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(prod_id) REFERENCES products(prod_id)
);
```

Comment: That's what I am saying @Mark

Comment: Can't I declare the foreign key on the same line as I declare the the column for the foreign key

Comment: @Mark yes you can declare it in same line, but you need to add comma after the column definition

Comment: @RaviSachaniya could you show me an example of how to do it on the same line